# How can I make Django render in the browser?

Tags: python, html, django, rendering

I'm trying to utilize Django forms.ModelForm function. However, I can not get it to render in the browser (Firefox and Chrome tested). In both browser inspection of code, the table\form does not show and there is no error coming from Django at all. The only thing that shows from the html file is the "Save button" Is there something I am missing here?

In Models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Product_sell_create(models.Model):
    product_product_sell = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    product_price_sell = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=500)
    product_volume_sell = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=500)
    product_location_sell = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    product_description_sell = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
```

Forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Product_sell_create

class ProductName(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product_sell_create
        fields = [
            'product_product_sell',
            'product_volume_sell',
            'product_price_sell',
            'product_location_sell',
            'product_description_sell'
        ]
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import ProductName


def products_create_view(request):
    form = ProductName(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        form = ProductName()

    context = {
        'form': form
    }

    return render(request, "sell.html", context)
```

sell.html

```
{% include 'navbar.html' %}
<h1> Upper test</h1>

<form>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>

<h1> TEST </h1>

{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Are you using template inheritance? Any change you messed up the blocks for it? Otherwise, install the django debug toolbar to see which templates are being used and the context being included. https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just did it, you would have problems POSTing your object too:

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import ProductName
from .models import Product_sell_create

def products_create_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProductName(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            prod = form.save(commit=False)
            prod.save()
            return redirect('../thanks')
    else:
        form = ProductName()

        context = {
            'form': form
        }

        return render(request, "form_test.html", context)


def thanks_view(request):
    query = Product_sell_create.objects.all()
    return render (request, 'thanks.html', {'query' : query})
```

forms.py and models.py keeps the same

sell.html:

```
<h1> Upper test</h1>

<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>

<h1> TEST2 </h1>
```

thanks.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>{{ query }}</h1>
    <h2>THANKS</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering, but sadly the problem is still there with the same resaults.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply, I have copied the codes you provided above but it still does not render. I created the thanks.html file but when I open inspect in the browser the {{ query }} part does not show either. It seems like my PyCharm simply will not render the " {{ }} " part even though it works for static and block

Comment: Thank you, everything works fine now! I forgot to change the views.py so i called in my old sell_view function instead of the new!

Comment: my first answer!! almost crying here

Answer (score 0):

did you create the 'sell.html' inside a 'templates' folder in your app folder?

MyApp/templates/sell.html

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes, it is located in that folder

Comment: as lucasrf said - The "return" have to be out of the `else` clausule.

 - The form = ProductName() after the form.save() is unnecessary

 - Remember specify the method and the action in the form tag